# Unable to click on an element using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, appium

```
<div id="_PHYLINSPortlet_WAR_PHYLINSPortlet_INSTANCE_o3P5_:form_PolicyContent_UI2:flatQuoteMenuBar:j_id7:VEHICLES" class="iceMnuBarItem portlet-menu-cascade-item">
<a class="iceLink" href="javascript:;" onclick="return Ice.Menu.cancelEvent(event);">
<span class="iceMnuBarItemLabel">Vehicles (1)</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I have to click on `vehicles (1)` menu
I tried lots of xpath selectors. `gettext()` is working but `.click` is not.

```
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='_PHYLINSPortlet_WAR_PHYLINSPortlet_INSTANCE_o3P5_:form_PolicyContent_UI2:flatQuoteMenuBar:j_id7:VEHICLES']/a/span")).click();
```

my 2nd xpath:

```
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[(@class='iceMnuBarItemLabel') and contains (text(),'Vehicles')]")).click();
```

Comment: i have used javascript method too click.. its not working

Comment: Are you getting any exception such as NoSuchElement etc.?

Comment: Does the element is clickable?

Comment: yes it is clickable..code is passing but action not happening

Comment: working only in debug mode

Comment: Put some wait before click on

Comment: Explicit, fluent wait nothing is working. still unable to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess issue is inside your `html` due to `javascript` was not defined properly.

**Your html code see the below line of code.**

```
<a class="iceLink" href="javascript:;" onclick="return Ice.Menu.cancelEvent(event);">
```

**After modified your html see the below line of code.**

```
<a class="iceLink" href="#" onclick="return Ice.Menu.cancelEvent(event);">
```

Now try to click on `webelement` using anyone of these below method.

**Try this way to click vehicle element.**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[contains(text(), 'Vehicles (1)')]")).click();
```

> OR

**Click Vehicle element using Java-script executor.**

```
WebElement vehicle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[contains(text(), 'Vehicles (1)')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", vehicle);
```

Comment: hi.. its not working.. it  worked once in debug mode.. but while running it is not working

Comment: can you share page url?

Comment: @ janish kapadia.. it got solved.. it was disabled somehow.. need to enable that element